# problem in character creation for mud game in python

Tags: python-3.x, character, mud

hello i  m new to python and i m making a mud game so i m stuck at a certain point where i have to create a character and following is my code. as i need to give 2 option to the  player with the description and then player will select one of the given choices. help me with the code in python.

```
def selectcharacter():
    character = ""
    while character != "Red pirate" and character != "dreed prince":  
        character = input("which character you want to choose? (Red pirate or Dreed prince ):")

    return character


def checkcharacter(chosencharacter):
    if (chosencharacter == Red pirate):
        print("the ability of the character is to fight close range battles and has 125 health and 50 armor!"),
    if (chosencharacter == Dreed prince):
        print("the ability of the character is to fight long range battles and has 100 health and 25 armor!")
    else:
        print("no character selected.please select the character!")


checkcharacter()
selectcharacter()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax errors and you need to pass a string as a function argument.

From what I can tell you want to first select a character and then change the output based on your selection.

Your code is almost working you just need to fix the syntax errors and save the selection in a variable, to be able to pass it to the next function.

```py
def selectcharacter():
    character = ""
    while character != "Red pirate" and character != "Dreed prince":  
        character = input("which character you want to choose? (Red pirate or Dreed prince ):")

    return character


def checkcharacter(chosencharacter):
    if (chosencharacter == "Red pirate"):  # should be string
        print("the ability of the character is to fight close range battles and has 125 health and 50 armor!"),
    elif (chosencharacter == "Dreed prince"):  # should be string
        print("the ability of the character is to fight long range battles and has 100 health and 25 armor!")
    else:
        print("no character selected.please select the character!")


selected_character = selectcharacter()
checkcharacter(selected_character)
```

The characters should be converted to strings, so you can check if they are equal to the passed argument `chosencharacter`. You also should use an `elif` instead of a second `if` because, otherwise the second `if` would get evaluated (to `False`) even if the first one is `True`.